# Windows workflows developed using vs2010 not continuing after migrating to vs2017

Tags: vb.net, workflow

We have a workflow created using VS2010.When we migrated the code to VS2017, the workflows that were created using vs2010 are not continuing.
But the ones created using VS2017 is continuing.

Comment: Would you please be more specific on what your question is?

Comment: we have an approval workflow form of many steps created using Visual studio 2010.When we migrated our code to VS2017, the forms that were initiated before migration , are not continuing (not going to next approver on approval).But when we create a new form using code created in VS2017 we are able to continue the approval process

Comment: can someone help plz @DjSh